# RSA Encryption, Key storage

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography, rsa

I'm writing a .NET application that uses a third party api. What is the best way to store the api credentials? I'm thinking of encrypting them using the RSACryptoServiceProvider, my question though is: If I encrypt my credentials using RSA I'll have to have the private key somewhere in the application to decrypt the credentials, wouldn't that mean that the encryption is basically irrelevant? Because anyone could just go ahead and take the encrypted credentials and use the the key I have to provide to decrypt the credentials.

What is the best way to handle the private key and keep from anyone who uses my application?

Can the key be read if I store it as a string somewhere in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to hide it from a determined attacker that already has access to your machine and your Windows username and password.

That being said, the [ProtectedData class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is probably the simplest way to make the data inaccessible to users that *don't* have appropriate credentials.

Comment: That's what I thought. I guess I'll just build the application with the encrypted credentials but only supply the decryption key to trusted machines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, key can be read if you store it as a simple string. But you can use SecureString class and minimize volatile access.

Also, never put the contents of a SecureString into a String: if you do,
the String lives unencrypted in the heap and will not have its characters zeroed out until the
memory is reused after a garbage collection.

Example from CLR via C#:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (SecureString ss = new SecureString())
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter password: ");
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) break;
                // Append password characters into the SecureString
                ss.AppendChar(cki.KeyChar);
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            // Password entered, display it for demonstration purposes
            DisplaySecureString(ss);
        }
        // After 'using', the SecureString is Disposed; no sensitive data in memory
    }
    // This method is unsafe because it accesses unmanaged memory
    private unsafe static void DisplaySecureString(SecureString ss)
    {
        Char* pc = null;
        try
        {
            // Decrypt the SecureString into an unmanaged memory buffer
            pc = (Char*)Marshal.SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode(ss);
            // Access the unmanaged memory buffer that
            // contains the decrypted SecureString
            for (Int32 index = 0; pc[index] != 0; index++)
                Console.Write(pc[index]);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Make sure we zero and free the unmanaged memory buffer that contains
            // the decrypted SecureString characters
            if (pc != null)
                Marshal.ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode((IntPtr)pc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really get it, wouldn't I need the key as plaintext somewhere in the code to generate the securestring? What's the point then in having it when it's around in plain anyway?